# How to deploying Vite react app on Github

Tags: reactjs, github, vite

I encountered following error while trying to deploy my React + Vite app on Github.
<kbd>Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\mypc\Documents\javascript\newsApp\build'</kbd>
Please help me solve this.

I followed some Youtube video and did the exact same thing they instructed. but nothing worked.

Comment: Could edit this question and include your package.json and your vite config file? It may be easier to find a solution with some more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Verify the GitHub Actions workflow file for correct paths and
   configurations.
2. try clearing cache as well as reinstall dependencies.
3. Check if the build directory exists locally after running npm run
   build.
4. check for typos in file path and again ensure dependencies are up to date